# Of course you do/don't?

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation, auxiliary-verbs, ellipsis

> A: I **don't** understand.
>
> B: Of course you do/Of course you don't

That's the question, which one is correct in order to confirm what "A" said?

Comment: We need more context. Both are correct, but mean exactly the opposite.

Comment: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/use-of-course-to-answer-negative-questions.2897506/ You can check it.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.If the second person  doesn't agree, the sentence should be affirmative

> But you do.

If the second person agrees, the sentence should be negative

> Of course you don't.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer:

You can to use just "of course", it is easy, short and clear.

Long answer:

We can to split the phrases and understand everything more.

> I [don't] understand. Negative
>
> Of course you [don't]. If you don't understand,  the sentence has to use the negative form.

Comment: Don't capitalize the first word after a comma! (Unless it is a proper noun.)

Comment: "It doesn't make any problem" is not idiomatic.

Comment: @Mattew In English, we use the bare infinitive after "can." It's **We can split,** not **We can _to_ split.**